# Can not access my JAX-RS resource after JBoss AS7 to WildFly 9 migration: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException

Tags: jboss, migration, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

After upgrading from JBoss AS 7.1.1-Final to Wildfly 9.0.1-Final, I get this exception when I try to access my servlet. Actually we're using Resteasy for web services and, a servlet to handle a GWT web page, with JBoss AS 7.1.1-Final everything worked just fine, however after the upgrade nothing work as expected, bellow you'll find a snippet of my `web.xml` file and `jboss-web.xml`.

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.afp.iris.sr.sco.scom.servlet.ScomIHMServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/components</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

When I try the following URL : `http://mymachine:8080/components/admin` I get the following exception

```
failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://mymachine:8080/components/admin
```

**#EDIT#**

And this is the way I implement my rest services

```
@Stateless(name = "myServices")
@Path("/")
public class myServices {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response myFuntion(@Context final HttpServletRequest request) {
        return secondFunction(request, null);
    }
}
```

and the same goes for resteasy resources, what could be the source of this issue, all suggestions are welcome !

Comment: How are you implementing your REST services? Could you please update your question with the code?

Comment: @aribeiro, I edited my post so that it contains the rest implementation .

Comment: FYI - check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).

Comment: Thank you @OndraŽižka, I didn't know such a tool exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your *web.xml* file is missing WildFly's RESTeasy bootstrap class.

Also, move your `resteasy.scan` property from your `servlet` as `init-param` and place it as a `context-param`.

Below are the changes needed to be made:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Perhaps you could try to use the [Servlet 3.0 Annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations) instead of using servlet mappings.

As an invocation example, you could do the following:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/components");

            request.setHeader("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
            request.setHeader("Content-type", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @aribeiro, as far as I'm concerned I think that resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix is not necessary If the url-pattern for the Resteasy servlet-mapping is not /*, and when I add scan option as a context param I get an exception, as for the listener I already have it in my web.xml, but I didn't want to post the whole file for brevity sack.

Comment: You're right, the `resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix` isn't required if the url-pattern is `/*`. What's the exception you're getting?